# Selenium post to Instagram

Tags: javascript, css, selenium, macros, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use Selenium in JAVA to click on the post button on Instagram on chrome (mobile emulation). It worked a few weeks ago when I made it but now it seems like Instagram changed something and i can't get it to work!

Inspect element of the button gives me this:

```
<span class="glyphsSpriteNew_post__outline__24__grey_9 u-__7" aria-label="New Post"></span>
```

And i tried clicking it on multiple ways:

```
WebElement post = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"react-root\"]/section/nav[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/span"));
```

AND

```
WebElement post =  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("glyphsSpriteNew_post__outline__24__grey_9.u-__7"));
```

I click it with:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", post);
```

I'm still a beginner so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: As a beginner did you start with _Automating_ **Instagram**?

Comment: I think the first question would be if you are sure you managed to locate the required element. if so, it might be that you need to use a different method to click it, such as Selenium's click(). What is the error\behaviour you are experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any javascript call to click an element.

find the button by visible text

```
    WebElement my_button = driver.findElement(By.linkText("New Post"));
```

or

```
    WebElement my_button = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("New Post"));
```

find the button by relative xpath

```
    WebElement my_button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@aria-label,'New Post')]"));
```

click on the button

```
    my_button.click();
```

Comment: This might not be true. As one who had to support 5 different browsers, there are some elements that a regular click() by Selenium didn't help, and i had to use javascript in order to click on the element.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it's not working too. Selenium passes it and doesn't perform a click, or in the other way I get no such element exception.